# Datagrid does not show buttons on row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I created a datagrid that looks like follow:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="false"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prefix" Binding="{Binding Prefix, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="true" Width="*" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Show">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>Details1</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>Details2</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>Details3</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Add" FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                Command="{Binding Create}" />
    </Grid>
```

My problem is, when I execute the wpf application:
[image]

I can not see any button in the datagrid row, but when I click in a column, then the button appears like:
[image]

Why? As you can see, in columns edit and delete, the button disappear too. So wirred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined CellEditingTemplate but forget to include the CellTemplate or maybe you only need CellTemplate??:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Show">

  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details1}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Button>Details1</Button>
       </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```